# AngularJS alpha only regex is accepting special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a very simple form with this regex pattern set on my first/last name fields `ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-z]{2,30}$/"` and both fields accept this value as being valid e.g. `Tester\^*&^%`. The first/last name should only accept alpha character a-zA-Z with a minimum of 2 characters and a max of 30.

Comment: Why we care about attention? I just asked a question about this on meta..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the wrong thing.

```
^[a-zA-z]{2,30}$
       ^
       |
```

It would match `\^` symbols because these symbols are comes under the range from [`A` to `z`](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Modified regex.

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2,30}$
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Sometimes you're working so fast you can't see the answer right in front of you.